# Edit page is not working(Undefinded variable branch) In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have edit page contains 3 fields company, dealership, branch, when I click one of the save list of the branch I need to show the details into the page but when I did this it shows undefined variable error throwing up, how to fix this and also need to update the form after listing the details in the corresponding fields

Edit Page

```
 @include('theme.header')
<?php
use App\Company;
?>
<div class="page-content-wrapper ">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="page-title-box">
                    <div class="btn-group float-right">

                    </div>
                    <h4 class="page-title">Branch Management</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end page title end breadcrumb -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Branch</h4>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['branchs.update',$branch->id]] ) !!}
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <?php
                                    $comp=Company::where('comp_id',$branch->comp_id)->first();

                                    $companies=Company::where('status','0')
                                        ->get();

                                    ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="br_id" id="br_id" value="{{$branch->br_id}}">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
                                        <option selected value="{{$branch->br_id}}">{{$comp->name}}</option>
                                        @foreach($companies as $company)
                                            <option value="{{$company->comp_id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dealership</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <?php
                                    $cn = App\Dealership::where('dlr_id', $branch->dlr_id)->first();

                                    $companies =App\Dealership::where('status', '0')
                                        ->get();

                                    ?>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="dealer" name=" dealer">
                                        <option>Select Dealership</option>
                                        @foreach($dealership as $dealerships)

                                            <option value="{{$dealerships->dlr_id}}">{{$dealerships->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Branch Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="branch" name="branch" value="{{$branch->name}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="page-title-box">
                                        <div class="btn-group float-right">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end col -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div>
</div>
@include('theme.footer')
```

Controller File

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Branch;
use App\Company;
use App\Dealership;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BranchController extends Controller
{
        public function index()
    {
        $companies = Company::where('status', '0')->get();

        $dealership = Dealership::where('status', '0')->get();

        $branches = Branch::where('status', '0')->get();

    return view('branch.index', compact('branches'));

    }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $branch_id = new Branch;
        $branch_id = Branch::orderBy('br_id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
        if (count($branch_id) > 0) {
            $id = $branch_id[0]->br_id;
            $id = $id + 1;
        } else {
            $id = 1;
        }
        $branch = new Branch;
        $branch->br_id = $id;
        $branch->name = $request->input('branch');
        $branch->dlr_id = $request->input('dealer');
        $branch->comp_id = $request->input('company');
        $branch->created_id = '0';
        $branch->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully saved');


    }



    public function edit(Branch $branch)
    {

        $branch=Branch::where('id',$branch->id)->first();
        return view('branch.edit',['branches'=>$branch]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $branch = Branch::findOrFail($id);
        $branch->status = '1';
        $branch->save();
        if ($branch) {
            $branchs = new Branch();
            $branchs->comp_id = $request->input('company');
            $branchs->dlr_id = $request->input('dealer');
            $branchs->name = $request->input('branch');

            $branchs->created_id = '0';

            $branchs->save();
            if ($branchs) {

                return redirect('/branch')->with('message', 'Successfully saved');
            }
        }
    }



    public function destroy(Branch $branch)
    {
        DB::table('branches')
            ->where('id', $branch->id)
            ->update(['status' => '-1']);
        return back()->with('message', 'Successfully Deleted');
    }


}
```

Comment: You are sending `'branches'` to your view and try to use `$branch`, See in your edit function!

Comment: you must post to the point instead of complete file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `branch` with parameter name `branches`. Change your controller code to:

```
 public function edit(Branch $branch)
{
    $branch=Branch::where('id',$branch->id)->first();
    return view('branch.edit',['branch'=>$branch]);
}
```

Comment: but its not working now it show another error,undefined variable dealership,its is edit page dealership select tag

Comment: just recheck your naming of variable, may be you are naming it with different name

Comment: @Abhijith: You need to change `return view('branch.index', compact('branches'));` to `return view('branch.index', compact(['branches', 'companies', 'dealership']));` in your `index()` function!

Comment: i have done that before but it doesn't get any values into select tag so i just showed the branches ,wrote code in index file like this,it works perfectly fine                      `<select class="form-control" id="dealer" name=" dealer">
                  <option>Select Dealership</option>
       @foreach(\App\Dealership::all()->where('status','0') as $dealership)
  <option value="{{$dealership->dlr_id}}">{{$dealership->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>`

Comment: @Abhijith you should keep your logic part on controller, try to follow `Hiren Gohel` comments

Comment: I know i have tried but it fails so i did like this,whenever i did try to do like @HirenGohel it show same error dealer or company variable not found

Comment: @Abhijith your code is fine, you just need to recheck your naming of variable

Comment: ok i will try thanks for your help guys @HirenGohel,@Sohel0415

Comment: @Abhijith: I don't think it's not working and it's working if you try to query in your view and then foreach it! The logic must be in controller and then send it to your view, this is the MVC strategy! Double check your naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `'branches'` from your controller and used `$branch` in your view! Try to change it in your `edit()` function like:

```
public function edit(Branch $branch)
{
   $branch=Branch::where('id',$branch->id)->first();
   return view('branch.edit',['branch' => $branch]);
}
```

And also, in your `index()` function change

```
return view('branch.index', compact('branches'));
```

To

```
return view('branch.index', compact(['branches', 'companies', 'dealership']));
```

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be correct just that you are sending branches instead of branch and when the view looks up for branch it's not available .. that's the error you are getting